# Android SetText while using Try Statement

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, android-alertdialog

So I have been researching for about 4 hours now on how I can fix this issue I am having.

Basically I am trying to create a Alert box and use data from a cursor to set the text of a TextView and the data is there but once i try to set it i get a null object reference everytime and I refuse to move past it :(

Here is the code in question:

```
 public void InputManual(long id) {

        @SuppressLint("AndroidLintInflateParams")
        final SQLite db = new SQLite(this);
        SQLiteDatabase X = db.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c;

        try {
            c = X.rawQuery("SELECT Product FROM Inventory WHERE _id =" + id, null);
            c.moveToNext();
            CreatePopup();
            Y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product);
            Log.v(TAG, "DATA: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Product")).toString());
            Y.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Product")));
            c.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The data is there when i use Log.v to display it and it is gone when i try to setText.

Here is CreatePopup():

```
    private void CreatePopup() {

    LayoutInflater Manual = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = Manual.inflate(R.layout.update, null);
    final EditText infoData = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.InfoData);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Update Quantity").setView(textEntryView).setPositiveButton("Save",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                    String Result = infoData.getText().toString();
                    String Done = "";

                    if (Result.length() == 0) {

                    }                     
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                }
            });
    alert.show();

}
```

The XML File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/Product"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/InfoData"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_data"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I have a listView onItemClickListerner that just passes InputManual(id) which would just be the id of the item in the database.

I'm at the point where I want to throw my keyboard because I can't figure out why it becomes null every time I try anything.

Any help would be appreciated even a different approach would be helpful.

My goal is to click on a item in the ListView and generate the Alert box with the item from the list so I can change the quantity to a different value but im just trying to set the TextView to whats in the ListView which is getting data from a database.

I probably didn't explain it correctly but I am willing to give any information that could help me solve this!

Long time browser of stackoverflow and I finally got to the point where I needed help because I can't google anymore :(

The actual error:

```
inventory W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
inventory V/MyActivity: DATA: CokeD
inventory W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Thanks!

Comment: as a general advice, narrow down the scope of the try-block as much as possible. Don't wrap everything in it.

Comment: `Y` is `null` because `findViewById(R.id.product);` returns `null`. Whereas the `NPE`. You seem to log another thing :             `Log.v(TAG, "DATA: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Product")).toString());`

Comment: you should post the full java class!

Comment: The `TextView` with ID `product` is in the `AlertDialog`'s layout, which is not attached to the `Activity`'s `View` hierarchy, so that `findViewById()` call isn't going to find it. Why not get it the same way you are the `EditText` in the `AlertDialog`? Actually, why not just add a `String` parameter to your `CreatePopup()` method, pass the `String` from the `Cursor` to it, and set it there?

Comment: @sschrass Yeah I just added the CreatePop() to it to see if I could eliminate the NPE, just trying to figure out a way to create the alertbox and have it set my textview to my database data and here I am.

Comment: @MikeM. Looks like we were typing at the same time

Comment: @MikeM.I feel so stupid, and I wasted like 4 hours trying to fix this with a try statement then what you said made me try it and it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> inventory W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

means that the TextView object is null, not the string value that you get from the database.

This means

```
Y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product);
```

is returning null, possibly because that view is owned by the dialog, not by the activity.

Try passing the string value to the CreatePopup() method as an argument, then you can call setText from there.  Like this:

```
private void CreatePopup(String product) {

    LayoutInflater Manual = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = Manual.inflate(R.layout.update, null);
    final EditText infoData = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.InfoData);

    //Add these lines
    final TextView productText = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.product);
    productText.setText(product);

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and answering I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by doing this

```
   private void CreatePopup(Long id) {

    LayoutInflater Manual = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = Manual.inflate(R.layout.update, null);
    final EditText infoData = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.InfoData);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final TextView TextSet = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.product);
    final SQLite db = new SQLite(this);

    SQLiteDatabase X = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c;
    c = X.rawQuery("SELECT Product FROM Inventory WHERE _id =" + id, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    final String Data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Product"));
    TextSet.setText(Data);
    c.close();

    alert.setTitle("Update Quantity").setView(textEntryView).setPositiveButton("Save",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                    String Result = infoData.getText().toString();

                    if (Result.length() == 0) {

                    }
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                    // ScanDataEmpty();
                }
            });
    alert.show();

}
```

Now I feel dumb.